# how can VS code support Go to definition

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I have two JavaScript files: config.js, app.js. In app.js I want to use function defined in config.js so I could use require().

*config.js*

```
module.exports = {
    somefunc: somefunc
}
```

*app.js*

```
var config = require('./config')
```

But I don't want to input the './' every time so I add a myRequire.js file.

*myRequire.js*

```
global.myRequire = function (p){
    return require('./' + p)
}
```

In that case I could use myRequire('config') next time instead of myRequire('./config'), which might looks more concise.

*app.js*

```
require("./myRequire")

var config = myRequire('config')
config.somefunc()
```

But I met a problem, that I cannot use F12(Go to Definition) in VS Code to find the somefunc function. So could someone tell me what should I do to make it work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You are introducing a lot more problem than what you are trying to achieve. What if you are requiring a file from different file path '../../here', './over/there'.

If you really want to require something without a path. You can create your own npm module so you can require it globally without paths OR you create a folder with index.js in it and you require all the things you need.

Comment: Actually it's a remaining problem in the project left behind by others and I just wonder how can I do to make VS Code to work in this case.